# How to properly set the username when simulating authentication with a token in a functional test

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, phpunit, functional-testing

I need to write a functional test in order to test that each role has the correct access to the pages.

In order to do that, I'm [simulating authentication with a token](http://symfony.com/doc/master/testing/simulating_authentication.html), but I slightly edited the logIn method, just to call it with custom `$username`, `$role` and `$firewall`:

```
protected function logIn($username, $role, $firewall)
{
    $session = $this->client->getContainer()->get('session');

    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($username, null, $firewall, $role);
    $session->set('_security_' . $firewall, serialize($token));
    $session->save();

    $cookie = new Cookie($session->getName(), $session->getId());
    $this->client->getCookieJar()->set($cookie);
}
```

So I am able to call it specifying which roles should have the fake user:

```
    $this->logIn('my_username@example.com', ['ROLE_USER'], "my_firewall");
```

Then I can test if the user is not allowed or not to access certain routes:

```
// check if the access is correctly denied to the ROLE_USER
$this->client->request('GET', '/route-not-allowed-to-user');
        $this->assertEquals(403, $this->client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());

// check if the access is correctly allowed to the ROLE_USER
$this->client->request('GET', '/route-allowed-to-user');
        $this->assertNotEquals(403, $this->client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
```

Those assertions work, the only problem is that in the view of the `route-allowed-to-user` I'm using twig to output the username:

`{{  app.user.username }}`

but it fails. I got status code `500` instead of getting `200`, and the following error:

> Impossible to access an attribute ("username") on a null variable ...

because `app.user` is not set.

How can I correctly set the user when simulating an authentication with token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved by editing the `logIn` method as follows:

```
protected function logIn($username, $password, $firewall)
{
    $session = $this->client->getContainer()->get('session');
    $authenticationManager = $this->client->getContainer()->get('security.authentication.manager');

    $token = $authenticationManager->authenticate(
        new UsernamePasswordToken(
            $username,
            $password,
            $firewall
        )
    );

    $session->set('_security_' . $firewall, serialize($token));
    $session->save();

    $cookie = new Cookie($session->getName(), $session->getId());
    $this->client->getCookieJar()->set($cookie);
}
```

and using [doctrine data fixtures](https://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures) in order to set users and roles.

Answer (score 0):

I think this happens because you didn't go through the authentication process and just created the user token which didn't trigger Symfony's event that store the user's username, roles and so on.

I did a similar thing recently by actually going through login form, filling data and sending it. Just like I was doing a real login attempt and it works well.

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

abstract class AuthenticatedTestCase extends KernelTestCase
{
    static protected $client;

    static public function setUpBeforeClass()
    {
        parent::setUpBeforeClass();
        self::$client = static::$kernel->getContainer()->get('test.client');
    }

    static public function login($login, $password)
    {    
        $crawler = self::$client->request('GET', '/test_admin/login');
        $form = $crawler->filter('input[type="submit"]')->form([
            '_username' => $login,
            '_password' => $password,
        ]);

        self::$client->submit($form);

        // Redirect after successful login
        self::assertEquals(302, self::$client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());

        self::$client->followRedirect();

        if (200 === self::$client->getResponse()->getStatusCode()) {
            // Redirected URL is OK
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```